# <Main /> component should show horizontal scroll. But doesn't

Tags: css, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-browser-kgzg3q?file=/src/App.js

I want the `<Main />` component to have at least width 1000px and if it doesn't, want a scroll-x to appear. But it doesn't.

Any clue here? Help me css ninja!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that the width properties of both the grid element and each direct child is overwritten by the grid-template-columns property. Therefore you need to create a child inside the Main component that sets the min-width and scroll properties there. I [forked](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-mclaren-pncptx?file=/src/App.js) your code and have written an example. I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <LeftIconBar style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "scroll" }}>
        <LargeText>hello world</LargeText>
      </LeftIconBar>
      <Sidebar style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "scroll" }}>
        <LargeText>hello world</LargeText>
        ...
      </Sidebar>
      <Main>
        <MainContent>
          <LargeText>last text</LargeText>
          ...
        </MainContent>
      </Main>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const MainContent = styled.div`
  min-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
`;

const Main = styled.div`
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 500px 1fr;
`;

...
```